# Special grouping in Linq

Tags: .net, json

I'm not quite sure how to explain this question

I have some thing like:

```
 0     1    A

 2     3    A

 1     1    A

 0     1    B

 2     5    B
```

I want to have a set like this:

```
A,[{0,1},{2,3},{1,1}]

B,[{0,1},{2,5}]
```

Comment: Where these items currently sitting on?

Comment: Is there any chance that you could provide your input and output data as compilable c# code?

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided any information about your data structures so I will use tuples here. To achieve what you want you can use LINQ [`ToLookup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549211(v=vs.90).aspx):

```
var data = new[] {
  Tuple.Create(0, 1, "A"),
  Tuple.Create(2, 3, "A"),
  Tuple.Create(1, 1, "A"),
  Tuple.Create(0, 1, "B"),
  Tuple.Create(2, 5, "B")
};
var result = data.ToLookup(
  tuple => tuple.Item3,
  tuple => Tuple.Create(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2)
);
```

You can print the lookup table:

```
foreach (var grouping in result)
  Console.WriteLine(
    "{0}: {1}",
    grouping.Key,
    String.Join(", ", grouping.Select(tuple => tuple.ToString()))
  );
```

The output is:

```
A: (0, 1), (2, 3), (1, 1)
B: (0, 1), (2, 5)
```

Instead of using `ToLookup` you can use [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.90).aspx). The difference is that once the lookup table is computed it is stored in memory. If you use `GroupBy` the grouping is performed each time the result is iterated using `foreach`. Also, if you data originates from a data source that supports LINQ (like Entity Framework) then using `GroupBy` allows the grouping to be performed on the server side which may improve performance.